# C : Linux Sockets: Recvfrom() too slow in fetching the UDP Packets

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recvfrom

I am receiving UDP packets at the rate of **10Mbps**. Each packet is formed of around **1109 bytes**.
So, it makes more than **1pkt/ms** that I am receving on **eth0**. The `recvfrom()` in C receives the packet and passes on the packet to Java. Java does the filtering of the packets and the necessary processing.

The bottlenecks are:

1. `recvfrom()` is too slow:fetching takes more than 10ms possibly because it does not get the  CPU.
2. Passing of the packet from C to Java through the interface(JNI) takes 1-2 ms.
3. The processing of packet in Java itself takes 0.5 to 1 second depending on if database insertion  or image processing needs to be done.

So, the problem is many delays add up and more than half of the packets are lost.

The possible solutions could be:

1. Exclude the need for C's `recvfrom()` completely and implement UDP fetching directly in Java (Note: On the first place, C's recvfrom() was implemented to receive raw packets and not UDP). This solution  may reduce the JNI transfer delay.
2. Implement multi-threading on the UDP receive function in Java. But then an ID shall be required in the  UDP packets for the sequence because in multi-threading the order of incoming packets is not guaranteed.  (However, in this particular program, there is a need for packets to be ordered). This solution might be  helpful in receiving all packets but the protocol which sends the data needs to be modified to add a  sequence identifier. Due to multi-threading, the receiver might have higher chances to get the CPU and  packets can be quickly fetched.
3. In Java, a blocking queue can be implemented as a huge buffer which stores the incoming packets. The  Java parser can then use the packets from this queue to process it. However, it is not sure if the receiver function will be fast enough and put all the received packets in the queue without dropping any packet.

I would like to know which of the solutions could be optimal or a combination of the above solutions will work. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"ID shall be required in the UDP packets for the sequence because in multi-threading the order of incoming packets is not guaranteed."*  Actually, the order of incoming UDP packets is *never* guaranteed, regardless of whether multiple threads are involved or not.  So if the order of packets is important than you need some kind of sequence number anyway.

Comment: I don't buy the idea that `recvfrom` takes 10 milliseconds, that seems ridiculously long. Are you sure you are just measuring the time taken to execute the system call?

Comment: Thank you. What percent chances that the packets will not be in order when the only sender hardware is in proximity , wired and there are no link congestions. Wireshark packet sniffer so far showed the packets were received in order.

Comment: I measure the time just before and after  calling recvfrom() and result durations varies greatly for every call.

Comment: You are performing 1K systemcalls/second. That won't change when you use java. And "passing the packets to java" will require *at least* another 2K packets per second. (plus context switches)

Answer (score 2):

How long is this burst going on? Is it continuous and will go on forever? Then you need beefier hardware that can handle the load. Possibly some load-balancing where multiple servers handle the incoming data.

Does the burst only last a short wile, like in at most a second or two? Then have the lower levels read all packets as fast as it can, and put in a queue, and let the upper levels get the messages from the queue in its own time.

Comment: Thank you. The burst would come every 5-10 minutes and last for may be 2-3 seconds depending on how much the data is. I have a question. What does it mean when you say reading all packets as fast as the lower levels can ? How can I control that ?

Comment: @sto_user For example have a thread that only does `recvfrom` and puts them in a queue, then the Java code gets packets from the queue instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be calling `recvfrom()` with your socket in blocking mode, in which case it will not return until the next packet arrives.  If the packets are being sent at 10ms intervals, perhaps due to some delay on the sending side, then a loop of blocking `recvfrom()` calls would appear to take 10ms each.  Set the socket to non-blocking and use something like `select()` to decide when to call it.  Then profile everything to see where the real bottleneck lies.  My bet would be on one or more of the JNI passthroughs.

Note that `recvfrom()` is not a "C" function, it is a system call.  Java's functions just add layers on top of it.